# Kill me please else I will be responsible for the murder of my children

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I wait for you, by taking deep breaths to start our journey. If you are travelling fast I don't breath(I am with no lungs for sure). You leave many children behind me during the journey and I will suicide for them at last. Some of my children have my body, but not the soul. Poor fellows.

But sometimes I will reincarnate to lead them in the right path. I will feed them again. Sometimes I am very cruel and will kill our own sons and daughters with the help of some murderers. One thing is sure if you are wrong in leading them, no mercy for sure, I will rise, and will take part in the conspiracy in killing them (I don't have a heart too :)).

But it is you who decide my death. Oh you are going to kill me for revealing this truth. Aren't you? RIP.

Clue 1:

> I do have two lungs and hearts. They are my sweet children now.

Clue 2:

> There were many incarnations and hope will have many of them soon. and love moderators.

Comment: Having seen the intended answer, I've undone my upvote. I don't think it's reasonable to expect people to work out that answer from the question as stated - sorry. There are too many unexpected interpretations, and too many other and more reasonable ways to interpret the clues.

Comment: In overall, I too find it difficult to get it right. So first lesson learned from the first puzzle.   Just don't write what you have in mind, analyze first and avoid unnecessary hints ;) Thanks for the input.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense considering the answer you are expecting

Answer (score 6):

It's more of an other possible answer but, could you be:

> Windows Task Manager

If you are travelling fast I don't breath:

> If a program is taking up too many resources (need too much to run fast), it can stall other programs on the machine OR if your machine if fast enough, this will never happen so Task Manager wouldn't be used

You leave many children behind me during the journey and I will suicide for them at last.

> By default the Task Manager will stay in front of all other open applications (children), and can close at the end.

Some of my children have my body, but not the soul

> Other programs are in windows having the same 'body' but not the same contents (soul)

But sometimes I will reincarnate to lead them in the right path. ... Sometimes I am very cruel and will kill our own sons and daughters with the help of some murderers

> You can start a new process from inside Task Manager, and end Processes if the user is a 'Murderer'!

One thing is sure if you are wrong in leading them, no mercy for sure, I will rise

> If you end some of the important processes (i.e System), the computer will 'rise' and take control (possibly shutting itself down or restarting somethings)

But it is you who decide my death

> Only the user can end the Task Managers dear life.

Answer (score 0):

I could be *way* off, but is it

> Doctor Who?

The hint (with "two hearts" and "this is my second birth") made me think of it immediately.

*I wait for you, by taking deep breaths to start our journey.*

> The first episode of the latest season of Doctor Who is called "Deep Breath".

*If you are travelling fast I don't breath(I am with no lungs for sure).*

> Do Time Lords need to breathe? I think maybe they don't. And the "no lungs" bit is negated by the hint.

*You leave many children behind me during the journey and I will suicide for them at last.*

> The Doctor has had many Companions, and on a few occasions he's given up his life for them (this caused e.g. the regenerations of Ninth->Tenth and Tenth->Eleventh Doctors).

*But sometimes I will reincarnate to lead them in the right path. I will feed them again.*

> The Doctor regenerates after he's been killed, and often returns to the same Companions as before (e.g. Rose and Clara).

*Sometimes I am very cruel and will kill our own sons and daughters with the help of some murderers.*

> The Doctor destroyed Gallifrey at the end of the Time War (or thought he did), causing the deaths of billions, some also killed by the murderous Daleks.

*One thing is sure if you are wrong in leading them, no mercy for sure, I will rise, and will take part in the conspiracy in killing them*

> I'm not sure about this bit.

*(I don't have a heart too :)).*

> Indeed: Time Lords have *two* hearts.

*But it is you who decide my death. Oh you are going to kill me for revealing this truth. Aren't you? RIP.*

> Again, not sure about this bit.

Comment: sorry, he is not a complicated guy.

Answer (score -2):

Is it

> Fungus || Fungi

Can relate some of the line to my answer. If it is right I'll provide explanation to my answer. Travelling now...

Answer (score -4):

> A text cursor

I wait for you, by taking deep breaths to start our journey. If you are travelling fast I don't breath

> It wait for us to start typing, by taking it's 'breaths'. If you are typing fast the cursor does not take it's 'breath'

You leave many children behind me during the journey and I will suicide for them at last

> The letters and characters are the children. When we save a document or question (here in SE) or search something in google the text cursor will disappear and it dies for the letters we typed.

Some of my children have my body, but not the soul.

> The letters 'I', 'l', '|' and '1' has the text cursor's body.

Sometimes I am very cruel and will kill our own sons and daughters with the help of some murderers. One thing is sure if you are wrong in leading them, no mercy for sure, I will rise, and will take part in the conspiracy in killing them (I don't have a heart too :))

> If the typed letters or words are wrong, we often edit the documents to correct them with the help of some murderers like 'backspace' and 'Delete' keys. Text cursor is also a part of the conspiracy and it does not have a heart for sure.

But it is you who decide my death.

> We decide when to save a document.

Clue 1: I do have two lungs and hearts. They are my sweet children now.

> When I completed typing the clue 1, there are a total of two 'lungs' and two 'heart' in the question. Obviously they are children of the cursor. So considering the question, it has two 'lungs' and 'hearts'.

Comment: I am disappointed by this answer, but even more disappointed by your clue explanations. What does a text cursor have to do with love?

Comment: That was pointing to the body of the cursor, I meant 'I'.

Comment: but the cursor is not related to love. The cursor does not love either of those things, nor does it stay in place in the sentence when you type it. It's a bad clue.

Comment: I have just explained that clue in the answer, just see the edit and hope you get that.

Comment: "I" is not "anybody". "I" refers to a specific person; namely the speaker of the word. "Anybody went to the store to pick up milk." has a very different meaning from "I went to the store to pick up milk."

Comment: Cube it by 2053!